# How to output a Rectangle[] to a ImageBox or PictureBox?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have an array of rectangle that consists of images, now I need to display it in a pop up form. How can I output the Rectangles to a ImageBox or PictureBox? Thanks!

```
 results = FindPeople.Find(frameImage, tryUseCuda, tryuseOpenCL, out processingTime, out peopleCount);

if (captureFrame)
      {
       popUpForm popUp = new popUpForm(results);
       popUp.Show();
       captureFrame = false;
      }
```

Pop up form

```
public popUpForm(Rectangle[] images)
    {


        foreach (Rectangle rect in images)
       {



       }

    }
```

Comment: Rectangle is a struct that consists of a Point (coordinates) and Size (Width and Height). What do you mean it "consists of images"? What is the effect you want to achieve by "output the Rectangles to a ImageBox or PictureBox"?

Comment: I am tracking people from a video. FindPeople.Find returns an array of Rectangle which consist of Point and Size of a tracked person. I want to display the tracked people in a Pop-up Form whenever I press a button @slawekwin

Comment: so you need to draw an image that is clipped from a bigger picture, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
public popUpForm(Rectangle[] images)
{
   Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
   using (var g = pictureBox.CreateGraphics())
     foreach (Rectangle rect in images)
       g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
}
```

Comment: InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       HResult=-2147467261
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=PeopleTracking
       StackTrace:
            at PeopleTracking.popUpForm..ctor(Rectangle[] images) in C:\emgu\PeopleTracking123\PeopleTracking\PeopleTracking\Form1.cs:line 30                                                                                                                              


pbOriginal.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(pen, rect);

Comment: pbOriginal.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(pen, rect); Yup I did, named it pbOriginal

Comment: Did you add pictureBox on your form?

Comment: Now error is on this line: using (var g = pbOriginal.CreateGraphics())

Comment: InnerException: System.NullReferenceException HResult=-2147467261
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure, that you have on your form pictureBox  with name pbOriginal ?